# Proving the quotient map is well defined, linear, and isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Reading Hoffman and Kunze, and there's a proof they write about quotient mapping that I have a few questions about:

[image]

Some points I'd like any explication on, if possible:

a) Why does it follow that if $\alpha + W = \beta + W$, then $\alpha - \beta$ is in $W$?

b) How does the fact that $T(\alpha + \beta) = 0$ show that $U$ is one to one? Couldn't it be the case that there are other elements in the nullspace besides just 0?

I looked this up because my homework for my linear algebra class involves proving the quotient mapping is well defined, linear, and isomorphic. Unfortunately our lecturer was absent in the last class, so I think we must research this on our own.

Thank you very much!

Comment: a) $a + W = b + W$ means for any $u\in W$ there is some $v\in W$ such that $a + u = b + v$ so $a - b = v - u \in W$.

Comment: b) $T(a - b) = 0$ menas $a - b \in$ null space which is $W$ hence $a + W = b + W$

Comment: All the elements in the quotient $V/W$ are of the form $\alpha + W$, so there's no more elements to check injectivity with.

Comment: @TonyPizza If you wish to answer the question. You should post an answer instead of writing a comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $W$ is a vector subspace you have $0 \in W$. It follows that
   $$ \alpha = \alpha + 0  \in \alpha + W = \beta + W.$$
   By definition this means that $\exists w \in W$ such that
   $$ a = b + w \iff a-b \in W$$
2. Suppose there exists another element different from zero which lies in the nullspace. That is, suppose there exists $\alpha \not \in W$ such that
   $$ U(\alpha + W) = 0.$$
   Then  by definition of $U$ and the above equation we get$$ U(\alpha + W) = T(\alpha) = 0.$$
   But this means that $\alpha \in W$ which is a contradiction.